# Usar TableView con un arreglo de otra clase implementada

Tags: java, scenebuilder

Clase Hija de Universidad

```
public class Alumno
    {
        protected String codigo;
        protected String nombres;
        protected String apellidos;
        protected int edad;
        protected float promedio;

        public Alumno(String codigo, String nombres, String apellidos, int edad, float promedio)
        {
            this.codigo=codigo;
            this.nombres=nombres;
            this.apellidos=apellidos;
            this.edad=edad;
            this.promedio=promedio;
        }//fin constructor

        public boolean tienePromedioCondicional(){
            boolean p=false;
            if(this.promedio<=3.1) p=true;
            return p;
        }

        /**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad codigo*/
        public String getCodigo(){
            return this.codigo;
        }//end method getCodigo

        /**Metodo de modificacion a la propiedad codigo*/
        public void setCodigo(String codigo){
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }//end method setCodigo

        /**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad nombres*/
        public String getNombres(){
            return this.nombres;
        }//end method getNombres

        /**Metodo de modificacion a la propiedad nombres*/
        public void setNombres(String nombres){
            this.nombres = nombres;
        }//end method setNombres

        /**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad apellidos*/
        public String getApellidos(){
            return this.apellidos;
        }//end method getApellidos

        /**Metodo de modificacion a la propiedad apellidos*/
        public void setApellidos(String apellidos){
            this.apellidos = apellidos;
        }//end method setApellidos

        /**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad edad*/
        public int getEdad(){
            return this.edad;
        }//end method getEdad

        /**Metodo de modificacion a la propiedad edad*/
        public void setEdad(int edad){
            this.edad = edad;
        }//end method setEdad

        /**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad promedio*/
        public float getPromedio(){
            return this.promedio;
        }//end method getEdad

        /**Metodo de modificacion a la propiedad promedio*/
        public void setPromedio(float promedio){
            this.promedio = promedio;
        }//end method setEdad

        /**Compara el codigo de this con un String u otro Alumno*/
        public boolean equals(Object other)
        {
            if(other instanceof String) return this.codigo.equals(other);
            if(other instanceof Alumno) return this.codigo.equals(((Alumno)other).getCodigo()) || 
                (this.nombres.equals(((Alumno)other).getNombres()) && 
                    this.apellidos.equals(((Alumno)other).getApellidos()));

            return false;
        }//fin equals

    }//fin class Alumno
```

Clase Main

```
public class Universidad
{
    public static final int MAX_ALUMNOS = 100;
    public static final int MAX_MATERIAS = 10;
    protected Materia [] materias;
    protected Alumno [] alumnos;
    protected int contadorMaterias;
    protected int contadorAlumnos;

    public Universidad()
    {
        materias=new Materia[MAX_MATERIAS];
        alumnos=new Alumno[MAX_ALUMNOS];
    }//fin constructor

    public boolean agregarMateria(String nombre, int maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo)
    {
        boolean agrego = false;
        Materia m = new Materia(nombre,maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo);
        if(!(this.contieneMateria(m))&&contadorMaterias<MAX_MATERIAS){
            this.materias[contadorMaterias++]=m;
            agrego=true;
        }       
        return agrego;
    }//fin agregarMateria

    public boolean contieneMateria(Materia materia){
        boolean existe = false;
        for(int i=0;i<materias.length&&materias[i]!=null;i++){
            if(materia.equals(materias[i])) {
                existe=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return existe;
    }

    public boolean agregarAlumno(String codigo, String nombres, String apellidos, int edad, float promedio)
    {
        boolean agrego = false;
        Alumno a = new Alumno(codigo,nombres,apellidos,edad,promedio);
        if(!(this.contieneAlumno(a))&&contadorAlumnos<MAX_ALUMNOS){
            this.alumnos[contadorAlumnos++]=a;
            agrego=true;
        }       
        return agrego;
    }//fin agregarAlumno

    public boolean contieneAlumno(Alumno alumno){
        boolean existe = false;
        for(int i=0;i<alumnos.length&&alumnos[i]!=null;i++){
            if((alumno.nombres.equals(alumnos[i].nombres)&&alumno.apellidos.equals(alumnos[i].apellidos))
            ||alumno.equals(alumnos[i])) {
                existe=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return existe;
    }

    /**Regresa el alumno en la posicion numero o null si no existe*/
    public Alumno getAlumno(int numero)
    {
        if(numero > 0 && numero <= alumnos.length) 
            return this.alumnos[numero-1];
        else return null;
    }//fin getAlumno

    /**Regresa el Materia en la posicion numero o null si no existe*/
    public Materia getMateria(int numero)
    {
        if(numero > 0 && numero <= materias.length) 
            return this.materias[numero-1];
        else return null;
    }//fin getMateria   

    /**
     * Elimina el alumno en la posicion numero.
     * Regresa el objeto eliminado si existe o NULL si no existe.
     * Reacomoda el arreglo para que todos los elementos queden contiguos y no queden vacios
     */
    public Alumno eliminarAlumno(int numero){ 
        Alumno tmp = getAlumno(numero);
        if(tmp!=null) {
            for(int i = numero-1; i<contadorAlumnos-1;i++){
                alumnos[i]=alumnos[i+1];
            }  
            alumnos[contadorAlumnos-1]=null;
            contadorAlumnos--;
        }        
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Elimina la materia en la posicion numero.
     * Regresa el objeto eliminado si existe o NULL si no existe.
     * Reacomoda el arreglo para que todos los elementos queden contiguos y no queden vacios
     */
    public Materia eliminarMateria(int numero){
        Materia tmp = getMateria(numero);
        if(tmp!=null) {
            for(int i = numero-1; i<materias.length-1 && materias[i+1]!=null;i++){
                materias[i]=materias[i+1];
            } 
            materias[contadorMaterias-1]=null;
            contadorMaterias--;
        }        
        return tmp;
    }

}//fin class Universidad
```

Controlador(Se encuentra la tabla aquí)

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Tab tabMateria;

    @FXML
    private Label lblMateria;

    @FXML
    private Label lblMaximo;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtMateria;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtMaximo;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdAgregarMateria;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdLimpiarMateria;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdEliminarMateria;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Materia> tablaMaterias;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Materia, String> clMateria;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Materia, Integer> clMaximo;
    ObservableList<Materia> materias;

    @FXML
    private Tab tabAlumnos;

    @FXML
    private Label lblCodigo;

    @FXML
    private Label lblNombres;

    @FXML
    private Label lblApellidos;

    @FXML
    private Label lblEdad;

    @FXML
    private Label lblPromedio;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtCodigo;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtNombres;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtApellidos;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtEdad;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPromedio;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdAgregarAlumno;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdEliminarAlumno;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdLimpiarAlumno;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Alumno> tablaAlumnos;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clCodigo;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clNombres;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clApellidos;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clEdad;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clPromedio;

    @FXML
    private Tab tablaInscripciones;

    @FXML
    private Label lblInscripcionMateria;

    @FXML
    private Label lblNumeroAlumno;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> cbMateria;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtNumeroAlumno;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdInscribir;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdLimpiarInscripcion;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Inscripcion> tableInscripciones;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clAlumno;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clMateriaInscrita;

    @FXML
    private Tab tabGrupos;

    @FXML
    private Label lblMateriaGrupo;

    @FXML
    private Label lblMateriaGrupo1;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> chMateriaGrupo;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> chGrupo;

    @FXML
    private Button cmdGenerar;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Grupo> tablaGrupos;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clCodigoGrupo;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clNombresGrupo;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> clApellidosGrupo;

    @FXML
    private Label lblInscripcionesUFPS;

    @FXML
    private ImageView imgLogo;


    @FXML
    void agregarAlumno() {

    }

    @FXML
    void agregarMateria() {
        Materia materia = new Materia(txtMateria.getText(),Integer.parseInt(txtMaximo.getText()));
        materia.setNombre(txtMateria.getText());
        materia.setMaximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo(Integer.parseInt(txtMaximo.getText()));
        materias.add(materia);
    }

    @FXML
    void eliminarAlumno() {

    }

    @FXML
    void eliminarMateria() {

    }

    @FXML
    void generarGrupo() {

    }

    @FXML
    void inscribirAlumno() {

    }

    @FXML
    void limpiarAlumno() {
        txtCodigo.setText("");
        txtNombres.setText("");
        txtApellidos.setText("");
        txtEdad.setText("");
        txtPromedio.setText("");
    }

    @FXML
    void limpiarInscripcion() {
        txtNumeroAlumno.setText("");
    }

    @FXML
    void limpiarMateria() {
        txtMateria.setText("");
        txtMaximo.setText("");
    }
```

En el View que lo realice con Scene Builder, tengo un tableView con el arreglo de alumnos, pero no se como implementarlo pues no se como funciona TableView y no se como realizar la conexión de una forma correcta, ya que he probado varias formas e intentando implementar las distintas formas en que pueda relacionar la lista de Alumno con la TableView, pero para hacer esto desde la vista debo usar el método que se encuentra en Universidad para que se añada al arreglo que se encuentra en alumnos, pero al hacer esto en el programa en la tabla no se ve nada.

Comment: Puedes compartir la clase del controlador de la vista donde se encuentra el `TableView`?

Comment: Actualizado, ya esta